# To show subset of normed linear space bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Book says ' A subset S of normed linear space X is said to be bounded if it is bounded with respect to the metric induced by the norm. Now follows exercise. Show that a subset S of X is bounded iff there exists c>0 such that ||x|| $\leq$ c for every x $\in$ S. I did converse part which yield 2c as a bound on metric but I am stuck on showing first way. First I thought it is easy considering d(x,0) but as it is only subset, no guarantee 0 is in S . Any hint. Thanks.

Comment: Let $c'$ be s.t. $||x-y|| \le c'$ for any $x,y \in S$. Fix any $y \in S$ (if $S = \emptyset$, we are done). Then, for any $x \in S$, $||x|| \le ||x-y||+||y|| = c'+||y||$, so just use $c := c'+||y||$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the normed space is vector space with metric defined by the norm. Suppose $M$ is bounded subset of normed space $X$ and $d$ be metric induced by the norm on $X$.
 Then by definition of Bounded set in the metric space, the diameter of $M$ that is

$\delta (M)=\sup d(x,y) =\sup ||x-y||= k<∞$

(Where $x,y\in M$)

Then for $x\in M$ and fix $x_0\in M$ and setting $c=k+||x_0||$ we have by triangle inequality,

$||x||=||x-x_0+x_0||≤||x-x_0||+||x_0||≤k+||x_0||=c$

Hence $||x||≤c$ for all $x\in M$

Comment: I think you are misusing "say"

Comment: @mathworker21 thank you sir. edited it.